# Phaser: How to rotate an isometric body?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, isometric

I am working with Phaser and its isometric plugin. I have this sprite with this body:

[image: iso_sprite]

As you can see the physics body doesn't match the actually visible body. I think I would need to rotate the body in order to properly match the visible body. I have no idea on how to do that and if there is another solution. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin is AABB based. What I wanted is not possible